# pipe password to `sudo` and other data to `sudo`ed command

Tags: bash, command-line, sudo, io-redirection, tee

Both of these commands work: (note the `-S` in `sudo` tells sudo to read the password from stdin).

```
echo 'mypassword' | sudo -S tee -a /etc/test.txt &> /dev/null
echo -e '\nsome\nmore\ntext' | sudo tee -a /etc/test.txt &> /dev/null
```

Now I would like to combine the two, i.e. achieve everything in just one line. But, of course, something like this doesn't work:

```
echo -e '\nsome\nmore\ntext' | echo 'mypassword' | sudo -S tee -a /etc/test.txt &> /dev/null
```

What would work? Thanks:) - Loady

PS: Minor unrelated question: is 1> identical to > ? I believe they are..

Comment: Yes, the 1 in 1> is implied.

Comment: And if you want to run everything on one line, can't you just command1 && command2?

Comment: @Q23 echo 'mypassword' | sudo -S && echo -e '\nsome\nmore\ntext' | tee -a /etc/test.txt &> /dev/null doesn't work..

Comment: This sounds like an extremely bad idea. What are you trying to accomplish? Why not just add a `NOPASSWD` entry to your `sudoers` file?

Comment: @Martin I'm trying to direct 'mypassword' to sudo, and \nsome\nmore\ntext to tee

Comment: @AnthonyWebber yes, that I understood, but _why_? Do you need call `sudo` from a script or a cronjob or something, so that it has to run non-interactively? Then the `NOPASSWD` option is probably far safer and less complicated than putting the password into a script and trying to pipe it into `sudo`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will do:

```
{ echo 'mypassword'; echo 'some text'; } | sudo -k -S tee -a /etc/test.txt &>/dev/null
```

The point is `sudo` and `tee` use the same stdin, so both will read from the same source. We should put "mypassword" + "\n" just before anything we want pass to `tee`.

#### Explaining the command:

- The curly braces groups command. We can look at `{...}` as one command. Whatever is in `{...}` writes to the pipe.
- `echo 'mypassword'` will write "mypassword\n" to the pipe. This is read by `sudo` later.
- `echo 'some text'` write "some text\n" to the pipe. This is what will reach `tee` at the end.
- `sudo -k -S` reads password from its stdin, which is the pipe, until it reaches "\n". so "mypassword\n" will be consumed here. The `-k` switch is to make sure `sudo` prompt for a password and ignore user's cached credential if it's used recently.
- `tee` reads from stdin and it gets whatever left in it, "some text\n".

PS: About I/O redirection: Yes you are right, `1>filename` is identical to `>filename`. They both redirect stdout to *filename*. Also `0<filename` and `<filename` are identical, both redirect stdin.

Comment: This way the password could be seen by another user that runs `ps aux`. Is that correct? In this same direction, this oneliner `echo "some text" | sudo -k -S <<< $PASSWORD tee /etc/test.txt` would work, or does it falls into the same problem of having only one STDIN?

Comment: @DiegoBandeira I tested your suggestion using here strings. The answer is yes and no! It doesn't work in bash, as I expected, but works in zsh.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late but I find this to work well:

```
sudo -k && echo -e "password\ntext" | sudo -S tee file > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This does not require multiple pipes and is simpler to understand.

```
> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This redirects all output including the one asking for password to /dev/null.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't put it in a comment, but note that you can combine the `-k` option with the already existing `sudo` command, i.e., instead of using

```
sudo -k && echo 'some text' | { echo 'mypassword'; cat -; } | sudo -S tee -a /etc/test.txt &>/dev/null
```

you can directly put the `-k` in the original `sudo`. It might even be "safer":

```
echo 'some text' | { echo 'mypassword'; cat -; } | sudo -k -S tee -a /etc/test.txt &>/dev/null
```

Comment: I edited my answer, thanks.