# How to pass two stdin to sudo?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, pipe, stdin

My goal is to write something to a file that needs superuser privileges and I want to do it with a single line of code. Steps I have tried:

I can pass a password from **stdin** to `sudo` by using its `-S` option:

```
printf 'password\n' | sudo -S cat /etc/test.txt
```

I can also pass a string from **stdin** to `sudo` to do something:

```
echo 'hello' | sudo tee /etc/test.txt
```

However, I am not able to pass the string and password on the same line.
Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391796/pipe-password-to-sudo-and-other-data-to-sudoed-command?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You wrote

> My goal is to write something to a file that needs superuser permission

One way to do this is to relax the permissions on the file so that it has (for example) group write permission. Then add the relevant users to that group. After a logout/login they will then be able to write to the file with no need for `sudo`.

Another "proper" way to do this with `sudo` is to create a script that manages the writing process, and then authorise that script within `/etc/sudoers` so that selected users don't need to provide a password. The big advantage of this is that the target file is not freely accessible even to your target users; your script can validate and sanitise the input before it's written to the file

Get a root shell. Keep this open and do not close it until you are sure that `sudo` is still working

```
sudo -s
```

Now create the script

```
cat >/usr/local/bin/write-to-file <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
#
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin        # Only necessary for a non-standard PATH

# Restart with sudo if we are not already root
[[ $(id -u) != 0 ]] && exec sudo "$0" "$@"


# Read just one line into the target file
head -n1 >/etc/test.txt
EOF
```

Still using this root shell, make the script executable and then add a line to `sudoers`. Change the inital `user` to the user account that is permitted to run `write-to-file` without a password, or `ALL` if any user is allowed.

```
chown root /usr/local/bin/write-to-file         # Ensure no-one else can modify the script
chmod a+rx,go-w /usr/local/bin/write-to-file    # Make it executable

echo 'user ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/write-to-file' >/etc/sudoers.d/write-to-file
```

Do not close the root shell yet.

In another (non-root) terminal, test the new script. If you get `write-to-file: command not found` then `/usr/local/bin` isn't in your PATH (run `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"`)

```
echo hello | write-to-file                      # Should not prompt for password
cat /etc/test.txt                               # Should contain "hello"

write-to-file < /etc/passwd                     # Multiline input
cat /etc/test.txt                               # Contains only the first line from passwd
```

Notice that we didn't even need to use `sudo` here. What's happened is that the script noticed it wasn't running as root, and restarted itself with `sudo`.

Comment: I think I understand your idea and I have learned from it. However, it will allow users to operate without entering their passwords. I don't want it at all. I want all users to have to use their passwords every time they want to configurate the target file. For this, my main script should ask for passwords and then pass them to sudo. Or something like that.

Comment: @e_moro remove the `NOPASSWD:` part of the `sudoers` entry and stop asking users for their passwords yourself. By default `sudo` will remember a user's authentication for a short while and won't keep asking for a password each time it's used

Comment: Anyway, sudo will prompt for the user password, whereas I want my script to pass it. (My program has a simple GUI to introduce it). I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Very good answer, informative and very clear. And seems to address the problem as stated, not the method as asked (which is a good thing: focusing on what is the goal, not what was the chosen route to reach it)

Answer (score 1):

Use a subshell:

```
(echo "password"; cat /some/file ) | sudo -S tee /etc/test.txt
```

Where `cat /some/file` can be any command producing output.

Answer (score -1):

This follows the @roaima's idea of using an auxiliary file to write the target one:

1. Logged as root, create a simple script called `write-to-file`, with the follow code:

   ```
   echo $1 > /etc/test.txt
   ```

(it must be placed at /usr/local/bin and must have only *root* execution permission).

2. As a normal user, you can run it from anywhere by:

   ```
   echo 'password' | sudo -S write-to-file "hello!"
   ```

In this way, one string is passed as stdin, and the other as an argument.

*note:* I don't know if this solution can result in a security hole. In my opinion, it should be as safe as the usual use of `sudo`.

Comment: Since in this scenario there is no limitation on what `sudo` can do, there's no additional security created or imposed by this solution. It's pretty much identical to `sudo -S bash -c 'echo hello, world >/etc/test.txt'` or (_don't do this_) `sudo -S bash -c 'echo hello, world >/etc/passwd'`. With open and uncontrolled `sudo` there is no validation to help prevent mistakes